# semi automated kick start in centos7

Tags: centos, kickstart, anaconda

I want to have semi automated kick start where option already made default in kick start file should not be editable by user i.e if i have by default made values for timezone language and other user should not able to modify this value and user can only modify value which is not mention in kick start file.

Direct case: I want user should be able to only modify installation Destination and other he should not be edit.[Here in below image user should be able to modify only box green mark screen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hO6LB.png)

Comment: Why not put the destination storage in the kickstart and fully automate it ?

Comment: We want destination storage to be selected by user in case there is multiple partition.In case in other partition he is having other OS.

Comment: Partitions will not be removed without `clearpart`. Anaconda does not support read only options far as I know, if it stops at a screen you can change things.  You may want to think about other ways of enforcing desired configuration post-install, a user who can boot any installer can do whatever they want to the OS.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response..Do you have any idea/suggestion to achieve this.??

Comment: We want some other field(Network and host name) to be modified by user at boot time only but field which we have already define should not be modified by user.Any other way of achieving this.

Comment: You might be able to achieve this with an [Anaconda Addon](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html-single/anaconda_customization_guide/).  In particular, read the section about ready states.